# How to get data like first capital by lower cases in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

New to mysql,

I have a table like this.

```
___|____
Id           |    name
1            |       a
2            |       b
3            |       c
4            |       A
5            |       B
6            |       C
```

---

What will be the query to get the result like this in sql

```
___|____
Id           |    name
4            |       A
1            |       a
5            |       B
2            |       b
6            |       C
3            |       c
```

Comment: meaning you want to have a custom id? Because the data looks like it mixed up.

Comment: And what MySQL version?

Comment: i dont get you but my  iD is Auto increment

Comment: when run version query i get this version `10.1.19-MariaDB
`

Comment: First table `1            |       a ` and `2            |       b`   second table (output) `1            |       A`  and `2            |       a`   the id's have changed.. That is what i meant and asked if your output id column has a custom order.

Comment: sorry now update my question , please check it.

Comment: Do you have only 1-letter names?  How do you want these sorted:  amx, Abc, Azz, Bcd?  Just first letter:  Abc,Azz,amx,Bcd?  Apply to each letter:  Abc,amx,Axx,Bcd?  (Etc)

Comment: Nice question. . . but i am beginner i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editted**

This seams to be the most easy way changed DDS idea into a more general working one for all MySQL versions..

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   id
 , name
FROM 
 Table1
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN name COLLATE latin1_bin BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
    THEN ASCII(name) + 31
    ELSE ASCII(name)
   END
```

**Result**

```
| id  | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 4   | A    |
| 1   | a    |
| 5   | B    |
| 2   | b    |
| 6   | C    |
| 3   | c    |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/2)

[Explaining View so you can see what happens on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/1)

Or the more stabile one because of the unique generated values for the calculated_ascii_value column.
[Explaining View so you can see what happens on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/5)

The other query is pretty complex..

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    Table1.id
  , Table1.name 
FROM (

SELECT 
 DISTINCT
   (
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@orderList, ',', number_generator.number), ',', -1)
     COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
   ) AS letter
FROM (

SELECT
 (@number := @number + 1) AS number
FROM (
 SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
) AS row_1
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
) AS row_2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @number := 0) AS init_user_param 

) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @orderList := 'A,a,B,b,C,c' /* add all to Z,z */) AS init_user_param

) AS letters
INNER JOIN
 Table1
ON
 letters.letter = Table1.name
;
```

**Results**

```
| id  | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 4   | A    |
| 1   | a    |
| 5   | B    |
| 2   | b    |
| 6   | C    |
| 3   | c    |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/4)

Note there are some things you should know

`COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` might be changed to `COLLATE utf8_bin` instead when your MySQL uses utf8 charset.

And `SELECT @orderList := 'A,a,B,b,C,c' /* add all to Z,z */` you need to might add more to `Z,z`

Comment: DB Fiddle is empty, out of curiosity where do you declare @orderList ?

Comment: You need to have https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/4 @EdenReich not a more simple query working is this one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/2 which is also in the editted answer.

Comment: @KarthikeyanT this CASE END check might be even better https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/5 notice the different between the calculated_ascii_value might be more stabile results while ordering.vs this one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzscasPGqAztQEeD1b9Jbn/1 notice 'a' and 'B' has the same values here

Answer (score 0):

this will make a new column 'newid' with the order you need

```
select newid = row_number() over (order by case when val between 'A' and 'Z' 
                                          then  ascii(val) -31 
                                          else ascii(val) end), *

from yourtable
```

Comment: Window functions (`row_number() over (..)`) is MariaDB 10.2.0+ syntax..

Comment: i doubt `case when val between 'A' and 'Z' ` would work correctly when the defual mysql connection/table charset/collision is case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I Just used database from w3schools, need to check if works in MySql.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY name ORDER BY UPPER(name), LOWER(name);
```

Comment: it will return a,b,c only

Comment: `select *... group by letter` is unvalid SQL.. on good servers it will tell you `ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.Table1.Id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: You have to add one by one each column to the group by after the ordering suggested